# Как удалить приложение из Google Play в новом дизайне?

Tags: android, google-play

Как удалить свое приложение из Google Play в новом дизайне консоли?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Здесь можно удалить приложение следующим способом
[image: Как удалить приложение]